# WCF consumindo WebService Java externo com HTTPS e proxy

Tags: web-service, wcf

Eu tenho um serviço WCF que consome um Web Service (desenvolvido em Java) onde preciso conectar com HTTPS usando um certificado. Até aí tudo funciona bem, porém, em ambiente produção meu cliente usa um proxy e não estou conseguindo estabelecer uma conexão SSL através do proxy.

Meu Binding do web.config do ambiente de desenvolvimento (que funciona) está assim:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="DOCeManagerServiceSoap12Binding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://example.com.br:443/DFeWeb/services/DOCeManagerService.DOCeManagerServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint/"
    behaviorConfiguration="TestServiceBehavior" binding="customBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="DOCeManagerServiceSoap12Binding" contract="DOCeManagerService.DOCeManagerServicePortType"
    name="DOCeManagerServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint">
  </endpoint>
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestServiceBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="01FE53"
                           storeName="TrustedPublisher"
                           storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                           x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"/>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

No ambiente de produção tentei modificar apenas este ponto:

```xml
<httpsTransport bypassProxyOnLocal="true" proxyAddress="http://proxy.example.corp:8080" useDefaultWebProxy="false" >
```

Recebo o seguinte erro:

> **Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'subdominio.example.com.br'. The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure**."

Já tentei inúmeras configurações mas nenhuma delas resolveu meu problema.

**Update 1:** Eu estava achando que o problema estava relacionado com o fato de que estou fazendo uma conexão SSL através de um proxy que não dá suporte à SSL, porém, se eu portar meu código para um console e informar o proxy consigo efetuar a conexão e consumir o método. Desta forma, não entendi como consegui conectar com SSL através de um proxy http pelo AppConsole e WCF não. Alguma ideia?

**Update 2:** Em recomendação dos colegas tentei rodar o serviço no IIS com meu próprio usuário (o mesmo que consegui conexão SSL através do AppConsole), mas não sei se fiz certo ou se falta algo, o serviço fica indisponível (**Service Unavailable**). Se alguém já fez isso e puder me auxiliar seria de bom proveito para eliminar a possibilidade.

**Update 3:** Atualizei a mensagem de erro que recebo quando tento conectar, adicionando o InnerException. Quando se diz **"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."** refere-se ao servidor que estou consumindo o serviço?

Comment: Você experimentou trocar o endpoint para o endereço de produção? A partir da mensagem de erro, levo a crer que você esqueceu de trocar o example.com.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Cleiton, mas eu eu já estou usando o endereço de produção, apenas alterei para postar aqui. No lugar do example.com estão os devidos domínios para o proxy e para o serviço externo. Abç

Comment: Eric tive um problema semelhante (sem SSL). Dava erro de proxy para a aplicação hospedada no `IIS` e funcionava direito numa desktop. No caso o problema era o usuário do `AppPool` que aplicação utilizava. Era um usuário com acesso diferente ao meu e por isso se comportava diferente de quando eu executava a app desktop. Você tem permissão se colocar diretamente seu usuário no AppPool e selecionar para ele carregar o profile do usuário pra testar?

Comment: Vitor obrigado pela resposta! Se entendi direito, eu preciso alterar o **identity** que meu **AppPool** roda, certo? Se sim, eu fui até **properties** do meu **AppPool**, na aba **Identity** escolhi a opção **Configurable** e coloquei o usuário que consegui com a aplicação console. Testei com dois usuários diferentes (um do domínio e outro local) mas em nenhum dos casos o serviço funcionou, recebo a mensagem _Service Unavailable_.Também tentei alterar entre as opções **Predefined**, _Local Service_ obtive a mesma mensagem e com a opção _Local System_ o serviço roda mas continuo sem conexão SSL

Comment: @VitorCanova me desculpe eu falei errado, quando eu coloco _Local Service_ o serviço roda sim (faltava reiniciar o IIS) mas passo a receber a mensagem **There was an error in serializing body of message synDOCeDownloadXmlRequest: 'Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\qwg3osjc.0.cs' could not be found
error CS2008: No inputs specified
'.  Please see InnerException for more details.** O problema ainda persiste.

Comment: Só pra confirmar, neste último caso não existem `InnerExceptions`?

Comment: Neste caso o InnerException é parte da própria Exception **Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS2001: Source file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\qwg3osjc.0.cs' could not be found error CS2008: No inputs specified** . O estranho é que não consigo rodar o serviço quando informo meu próprio usuário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após muita pesquisa e ajuda dos colegas da comunidade, descobri que o problema era a falta de configuração do **Winhttp (Microsoft Windows HTTP Services)** que não utiliza a mesma configuração de proxy para usuários ou que está no IE, é como se fosse algo separado, somente para os serviços. Basicamente você precisa configurar sempre que um serviço se comunicar através do HTTP para acesso externo através do proxy.

Abaixo vou colocar os procedimentos que executei no ambiente (server 2003) através da ferramenta **"proxy.cfg.exe"**

1. Executar o prompt de comando com direitos de administrador
2. Para visualizar a configuração atual, digite apenas o nome da ferramenta `proxycfg.exe`.
3. Para configurar um proxy, use o comando `proxycfg.exe -p proxy.example.com:8080 "<local>"`. 
   Se atente em substituir o proxy corretamente. O último parâmetro `"<local>"` é opcional e equivale onde o proxy deve ser ignorado.
4. Reinicie o IIS e pronto!

Para o windows 2008 as coisas mudam um pouco, o proxycfg não existe mais e a configuração se dá pelo **"netsh.exe"**

1. Execute o prompt de comando ou power shell com direitos de administrador
2. Para visualizar a configuração atual, digite o comando `netsl.exe Winhttp show proxy`.
3. Para configurar um proxy, use o comando `netsh.exe Winhttp set proxy proxy.example.com:8080 "<local>"`.Se atente em substituir o proxy corretamente. O último parâmetro `"<local>"` é opcional e equivale onde o proxy deve ser ignorado.
4. Reinicie o IIS e pronto!

Bem para o meu caso isso foi suficiente para conseguir **eliminar** a mensagem de erro:

> **Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'subdominio.example.com.br'. The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."**

No Stackoverflow.com há uma resposta passada pelo colega Raul Almeida que descreve possíveis problemas, inclusive menciona este que postei. Se você tem a mesma mensagem de erro e não conseguiu resolver com este procedimento que descrevi, [recomendo dar uma olhada nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap)!

Fontes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925(v=vs.85).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc731131(WS.10).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384069(v=vs.85).aspx

Espero ajudar alguém com isso!

Answer (score 3):

Não é a primeira vez que vejo este tipo de situação acontecendo.

Muitas vezes esquecemos de planejar o ambiente onde a nossa aplicação irá rodar e deixamos passar despercebido este tipo comum de situação.

Já que não era previsto o proxy, a rede pode ser configurada para liberar o acesso da sua aplicação/máquina/porta para que não seja necessária a autenticação no proxy.

Se não for possível, você precisa configurar um tipo de autenticação programaticamente.

O seu config deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="...2Soap12">

                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>
                <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="...." requireClientCertificate="???"/>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
```

E o cliente que irá realizar a chamada deve ser configurado com um tipo de autenticação apropriado ( plain, kerberos, etc ):

```
client.ClientCredentials = ???
```

Porém deixo o alerta que acertar todas estas configurações é trabalhoso na primeira tentativa e que por isso eu recomendo evitar de uma vez o proxy.

Comment: Realmente muitas vezes falta planejamento, talvez muitas vezes por falta de conhecimento da tecnologia usada(meu caso). Talvez por isso, eu não entendi muito bem a resposta, você disse que no cliente que irá fazer a chamada devo informar as credenciais, na verdade meu serviço é cliente do webservice externo, este por sua vez precisa de certificado e o acesso externo quem deve fornecer é o proxy que não me pede nenhuma autenticação, pois no Appconsole que fiz consegui conexão SSL apenas informando o **proxyAddress="http://proxy.example.corp:8080"** e **useDefaultWebProxy="false"**. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Visto a mensagem de erro apresentada, [uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap) no stackoverflow.com que você deve atentar-se a algumas hipóteses entre elas a de que o novo computador não possua a cadeia de certificação que traz confiabilidade ao certificado que você está utilizando.

Caso não seja o caso, a resposta lista outros pontos que você pode verificar. Caso tenha dificuldade no inglês, sinalize.

Comment: Obrigado, foi lá que encontrei a resolução para meu problema!